# phpseclib SSH2: Why won't my commands run?

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh, minecraft, phpseclib

I'm trying to make a web interface for managing my Ubuntu hosted Minecraft server. I use screen in order to make the console re-accessible. I don't get why the following code does not work:

```
    $ssh->read('quadrplax@quadrplax-laptop:~$');
    $ssh->write("screen -rd\n");
    $ssh->write("stop\n");
```

Now, don't ask me why, but if I add in this useless code:

```
    $randid=rand(0, 1000000);
    $consolemsg=strval($randid);

    $ssh->read('quadrplax@quadrplax-laptop:~$');
    $ssh->write("screen -rd\n"); // note the "\n"
    $ssh->write("say Stopping server - ID:".$consolemsg."\n");
    echo $ssh->read(" [INFO] [Minecraft-Server] [Server] Stopping server - ID:".$consolemsg);
    $ssh->write("stop\n");
```

Then it will be able to get the screen session disconnected, but the page will then load for minutes before timing out. Sorry for how stupid this is, I can't find any good guides for phpseclib, they all are copies of the same guide and don't give any long examples. I have been able to get some things to work, for example my suspend code somehow works:

```
    $ssh->read('quadrplax@quadrplax-laptop:~$');
    $ssh->write("sudo pm-suspend\n");
    $ssh->setTimeout(5);
    $output = $ssh->read('#[pP]assword[^:]*:|quadrplax@quadrplax-computer:~\$#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
    $ssh->write("FAKEPASSWORD\n");
```

Sorry for formatting errors or anything, first time here. I had a hard time getting this post to submit. Can someone help me out with this?

Edit: Fixed a copy-paste error

Comment: That quotation is a copy paste error. There's a comment there in the actual code I never bothered to remove: '// note the "\n"'.

Comment: I don't believe the `$ssh->setTimeout(5);` should be necessary in the last code snippet you posted. As for the rest...  idk can you enable logging and post the logs? eg. add `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3);` at the top of your file. If you could then put the log on pastebin.com and post the link here that'd be helpful!